# Gateway-service. 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm having some troubles related to the gateway service in Spring boot. I have the following .yml

```
  #spring.profiles.active: local
server:
  port: 80
  #ssl:
  #  enabled: true # Uses self-signed certificate because no key-store configuration is specified.

internal.lb.uri: http://34.125.111.144
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: customers
          uri: ${internal.lb.uri}:9001
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/customers**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - id: employees
          uri: ${internal.lb.uri}:9000
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/employees**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - id: suppliers
          uri: ${internal.lb.uri}:9002
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/suppliers**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - id: webapp
          uri: ${internal.lb.uri}:9003
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
```

When I run it, it runs perfect! But once I try to connect to localhost it says the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNfgO.png)

So I don't know what's going on! I can't find any solution!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your ->
internal.lb.uri: http://34.125.111.144

and replace it by ->
internal.lb.uri: http://localhost

Then restart all the microservices again.

That worked for me